# Jira JQL find backlockitems with label and include their subtasks without a plugin

Tags: jira, jql

I need to select all backlogitems AND their corresponding subtasks. However, only the backlogitems have the label i'm looking for. Therefore the subtasks are always filtered out.

```
( issuetype = "Backlog Item" ) AND labels="Implementation" AND project = MY_PROJECT
```

I cannot install or use any plugin. All solutions I could find use plugins.